# How to prevent same login details with multiple browser in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do i **stop multiple user login with same email and password** once the user already logged into the website.

**For example:**

```
if a  user already login from chrome and user trying to login from firefox
then system should automatically destroy first session which is created 
from chrome.
```

Comment: I think you need to store user info which is logged in and check with them if login from another place/browser.

Comment: how to chk login from another place/browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738979/same-logged-in-user-assigned-different-session-ids-in-different-browsers

Comment: In your DB which is store already logged in.

Comment: You can use the method mentioned in above link just instead of merging the session, destroy the first one and create new one.

Comment: what have you **tried** so far **yourself**?

Comment: i have followed the following link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435793/how-do-i-stop-multiple-user-login-with-same-email-and-password-once-user-already

Comment: Can you show me ur code?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to store your sessions in a database. Then when a user re-attempts to login you can easily delete them from the database. You would probably require a table that stores a `session-userID` link but that is kinda the solution I use.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field like "is_loggedin" in your user table
And update this field value to 1 when any user login.
And update it to 0 when any user logout.

At the time of login you can check this field value if it is 1
than user is logged in at other place and you should return your warning message.